# $P$ is projection matrix iff $A$ is reflection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

I have the following definition

> An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is a reflection matrix if and only if $A^2 = I$ and $A^T= A$. A projection matrix is $P = 1/2(A+I)$.

I was wondering if I can conclude that $P$ is a projection matrix if and only if $A$ is a reflection matrix. If it can be said can you please explain why?

Assuming that this is true can I say that $A^2 = I$ and $A^T = A$  if and only if $P^2 = P$ and $P^T=P$?

Comment: Well, $P$ is *projection* if and only if $P^2=P$, so according to your definition, the only reflection matrix that is also a projection is $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re restricting $P$ to an orthogonal projection, consider one of the standard ways to construct the (orthogonal) reflection of a vector relative to some subspace of $\mathbb R^n$: find the orthogonal *rejection* of the vector from that subspace and reverse it. That is, if $W\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a subspace and $\pi_W$ is orthogonal projection onto $W$, then the reflection of a vector $v$ in $W$ is $\rho_Wv=\pi_Wv-(v-\pi_wv)=2\pi_Wv-v$, or, in matrix form, $Av=(2P-I)v$, from which your equation $P=(A+I)/2$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

No, a projection matrix $P$ satisfies $P=P^2$, and is not symmetric in general. Only orthogonal projection matrices are symmetric. Furthermore $P^2=I$ would imply $P=I$. So symmetric involutory matrices $A$ with $A^2=I$ are something different than projection matrices.

Edit: You have added the relation $P=(A+I)/2$. Then of course we have
$$
P^2=(A+I)^2/4=(A^2+2A+I)/4=(I+A)/2=P.
$$

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention, by I was talking about orthogonal projection matrices

Comment: So the last line you wrote shows that P is a projection matrix if and only if A is a reflection matrix.?